# Malformed nginx 307 redirect response?

Tags: nginx, amazon-web-services, http, redirect

I have an Nginx configuration that 307 redirects from http to https. There are existing client applications that connect to http and send data via POST requests. The clients are .Net services using HttpWebRequest. Just using 301 redirect results in the POST data getting dropped from the request.

I have the 307 redirect working in my local test environment, but when deployed to the production server the redirect message is getting corrupted, and the clients are throwing an exception.

This is the working response I get in my test environment:
[image: Working 307 redirect]

And this is what I get from the production environment
[image]

You can see how the packet looks different, what could be causing the different responses? The older version of nginx?

Comment: How did you generate this 307?

Comment: This block in the .conf file sets up the redirect server{
    listen 80;
    server_name name;
    return 307 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

Comment: Generally it's a good idea to run the same version of software in your test and prod environments (except when you are testing an upgrade).  I have no idea if this is the cause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Versions of nginx prior to 1.1.16 did not properly support returning 307 responses.

The change log reads, in relevant part:

```
Changes with nginx 1.1.16                                        29 Feb 2012

    *) Feature: the "return" and "error_page" directives can now be used to
       return 307 redirections.
```

I recommend you bring your production (and your development!) server [up to date](http://nginx.org/en/linux_packages.html#stable) if you need this functionality. nginx 1.0.5 is very old at this point.

Comment: No, 1.1.19 is the one that's merely very old, 1.0.5 is ancient.